# SQL statement to obfuscate phone nums in DB2

Tags: db2

I am new to DB2 Express-C and am wondering if a SQL statement can be run in DB2 that can go thru all tables and change (could be scramble, replace, random, whatever) any 10-dgit phone numbers found. In a nut shell, do a global search and replace on all fields, in all tables, to obfuscate any phone numbers (private info).

I need to hand off a client's DB2 database (17 tables) to a software vendor to do some reporting but I have been tasked with making sure NO real phone numbers get exposed in the process. I'm sure there is a SQL statement that could handle a single table (then I could go into DB2 Control Center and run it 17x) but I am looking for a quick, clean way to 'prep' this DB before sending it out.

Thanks in advance to you DB2 gurus!

Mike

Answer (score 0):

If you want to hide information in db2, you should use [these functions](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v10r5/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.sec.doc/doc/c0005815.html):

- ENCRYPT
- DECRYPT_BIN
- DECRYPT_CHAR
- GETHINT

Or the IBM Database [Encryption Expert](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v10r5/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.sec.doc/doc/c0053466.html)

The functions are for varchar, and I think you have a int column, so it does not work.

However, you can hide all telephone numbers from different tables by applying a UDF, and querying the catalog.

For example, your UDF (user defined function) could mutiply the telephone by a given number that you only know. Then, in order to decrypt it, you just have to divide by the same number.

Then, to apply this procedure to all tables, you have to query the catalog. For example,

```
select tabschema, tabname
from syscat.columns
where colname like 'PHONE%'
```

Once, you are sure of the tables, you could update them with your UDF

```
select 'update ' || trim(tabschema) || '.' || trim(tabname) || ' set ' || trim(colname) || ' = myUDF(' || colname || ', 5) ;' from syscat.columns where colname like 'PHONE%'
```

Let's say 5 is your encryption number.

You just have to execute the output in order to hide the telephones.